# Bash - extract date from string and reformat

Tags: linux, bash

In a bash script I'm trying to get the date of the last login from `last`

eg:

```
last bob -n 1
```

Which gives me:

```
bob     tty1    Fri Jul 18 10:43 - 10:43  (00:00)

wtmp begins Wed Feb  5 17:47:13 2014
```

and then extract the date from that string, and insert it into the `lastb` to get the number of failed logins since last successful one.

eg:

```
lastb bob -t $MYLASTLOGIN
```

[man lastb](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lastb) shows the date format needs to be `-t YYYYMMDDHHMMSS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
user=bob lastb $user -t $(date -d "$(last $user | head -n 1 | tr -s '[:space:]' '\t' | cut -f 4-7)" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
```

More readably

```
 user=bob
last_login=$(last $user | head -n 1 | tr -s '[:space:]' '\t' | cut -f 4-7)
datetime=$(date -d "$last_login" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
lastb $user -t $datetime
```

Note that my `last` output looks a little different from yours, with an extra field: adjust your `cut` columns accordingly

```
$ last glennj -n 1
glennj   pts/7        :0               Sun Jul 20 19:01   still logged in   

wtmp begins Fri Jul  4 21:15:28 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try matching the date string with `grep`, storing the result in a variable, using `date` to convert and putting the result of that into the command:

```
LOGINDATE=$(last bob -n1 | egrep -o '[A-Z][a-z]{2} [A-Z][a-z]{2} [0-9]{1,2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}')
BLOCKDATE=$(date --date="$LOGINDATE" "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
lastb bob -t $BLOCKDATE
```